# how to set iam permissions to invoke cloud function gen2?

Tags: terraform, google-cloud-functions, permission-denied, google-cloud-iam

I have deployed a cloud function on gcp with terraform. But when I invoke try to it, It gives an error

> Your client does not have permission to get URL /getAllEmployees from this server.

Below is my terraform code

```
provider "google" {
  project     = var.project_id
  region      = var.region
  credentials = "../tf-key.json"
}

resource "google_storage_bucket" "bucket" {
  name     = "${var.project_id}-bucket1"
  location = var.region
}

resource "google_storage_bucket_object" "source_code" {
  name   = "objects"
  bucket = "terraform-cloud-functions-ems-bucket1"
  source = "D:/gcf-terraform/gcf-1.zip"
}

resource "google_cloudfunctions2_function" "function" {
  name        = "getAllEmployees"
  location    = "us-central1"
  description = "Retrieve all employees."

  build_config {
    runtime     = "go121"
    entry_point = "GetAllEmployees"

    source {
      storage_source {
        bucket = "terraform-cloud-functions-ems-bucket1"
        object = "objects"
      }
    }
  }
  service_config {
    min_instance_count             = 1
    max_instance_count             = 10
    available_memory               = "128Mi"
    timeout_seconds                = 120
    all_traffic_on_latest_revision = false
    service_account_email          = "terraform-gcf@terraform-cloud-functions-ems.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
  }
}

resource "google_cloud_run_service_iam_binding" "default" {
  location = "google_cloudfunctions2_function.function.location"
  service  = "google_cloudfunctions2_function.function.name"
  role     = "roles/run.invoker"
  members  = ["allUsers"]
}
```

Resource "google_cloud_run_service_iam_binding" is not getting deployed.

I was expecting my function to get invoked. I have provided 'members' = ["allUssers"] in my code. But it still doesn't work.

I will appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

I think your issue is due to your resources not created in the right order, in `Terraform` you can specify dependencies between some resources, in order to create them in the right order.

In your case, the resource `google_cloud_run_service_iam_binding` needs to be created before the `google_cloudfunctions2_function` resource, example :

```
provider "google" {
  project     = var.project_id
  region      = var.region
  credentials = "../tf-key.json"
}

resource "google_storage_bucket" "bucket" {
  name     = "${var.project_id}-bucket1"
  location = var.region
}

resource "google_storage_bucket_object" "source_code" {
  name   = "objects"
  bucket = "terraform-cloud-functions-ems-bucket1"
  source = "D:/gcf-terraform/gcf-1.zip"
}

resource "google_cloud_run_service_iam_binding" "default" {
  location = "google_cloudfunctions2_function.function.location"
  service  = "google_cloudfunctions2_function.function.name"
  role     = "roles/run.invoker"
  members  = ["allUsers"]
}

resource "google_cloudfunctions2_function" "function" {
  depends_on = [
    google_cloud_run_service_iam_binding.default
  ]

  name        = "getAllEmployees"
  location    = "us-central1"
  description = "Retrieve all employees."

  build_config {
    runtime     = "go121"
    entry_point = "GetAllEmployees"

    source {
      storage_source {
        bucket = "terraform-cloud-functions-ems-bucket1"
        object = "objects"
      }
    }
  }
  service_config {
    min_instance_count             = 1
    max_instance_count             = 10
    available_memory               = "128Mi"
    timeout_seconds                = 120
    all_traffic_on_latest_revision = false
    service_account_email          = "terraform-gcf@terraform-cloud-functions-ems.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
  }
}
```

In this example, I specified a dependency and the `google_cloudfunctions2_function` depends on the `google_cloud_run_service_iam_binding` vie the following code snippet :

```
depends_on = [
   google_cloud_run_service_iam_binding.default
]
```